How to exclude or skip a particular day of the week in the query calculation in Datdog?
In the metric for a Datadog monitor, I have a query that sums a particular value daily and alerts when it exceeds a threshold. I want this monitor to exclude/skip calculating for Sundays alone. What additional query/formula do I add in order to achieve this?

You can use a custom schedule with an RRULE to achieve this.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/guide/custom_schedules/?tab=day#rrules
FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA


This is great, thanks! Just to add, I wasn't able to update the existing monitor but had to clone it  and create a new monitor to use this feature. Custom schedule appears as Beta as of today while editing Datadog monitor
